# Calculate SLA in days, hours and minutes

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet calculating SLA s between two dates and displays in the format X Days X Hours X Minutes.

```
=IF('My Access Month Data'!I3="","",INT(D3-C3)&" Days "&HOUR(MOD(D3-C3,1))&" Hour "&MINUTE(MOD(D3-C3,1))&" Minutes")
```

I am looking to run a calculation on the results if the above formula that will basically give me a `Y` if the results are less than or equal to 1 day 0 hours and 0 minuets and a `N` if the time has exceeded this.

Comment: Do you really want to use that formatting? You could use =IF(MINUTE(D3-C3) < 1440, "Y", "N")

Comment: Im afraid I do, the specific requirements where the sla need to be reported in readable form, so at a glance you can see the time it took to process in Days, hours and Mins

Comment: @BasDeBeer - Do you need the [MINUTE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MINUTE-function-AF728DF0-05C4-4B07-9EED-A84801A60589) and the `1440`? `=IF(D3-C3 < 1, "Y", "N")` or `=IF(SIGN(INT(D3-C3)), "N", "Y")` should do.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, that has seemed to do the trick, I made one small alteration to include <= to 1. I have another issue, as I would like to return a blank if there is no data in the E cell, I am using the following formula:

IF(E2="","",(D2-C2 <= 1, "Y", "N"))

But im hitting errors, If I drop the brackets from the D2-C2 calculation im getting a too many arguments error.

Is my Syntax off?

Comment: Have you looked at the solution from @Jeeped?  It appears like you can read the original dates and accomplish the same task, or is your original data coming in like this from an external source, and this formula was just meant to demonstrate how the field appears?

Comment: Sorry Yes Jeeped responce has worked a treat